# Paypal returning Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: php, paypal

I've have managed to get all of the way to the end of the initial payment request to Paypal, but have now hit a brick wall.

The following code tries to redirect to Paypal

```
foreach ($result->links as $link)
{
    if($link->method == "REDIRECT")
    {
        $redirect_url = $link->href;
    }
}

header("Location: " . $redirect_url);
```

The $redirect_url is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6H386134VK1125507.

However, this returns the following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6H386134VK1125507. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:1000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Is there something else I need to set up in Paypal, or do I need to change something in the redirect?

Comment: why would you want to make an ajax request to that url?

Comment: I'm following the Paypal Tutorial at https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox and am looking to redirect the user to Paypal to confirm payment as per step 3 of 5.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load` means you made a request with ajax to `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/` which is, of course, not allowed. You just need to redirect the user to that url. Because, if I click on that url above, it's working.

Comment: I'm assuming you are making an ajax request where you have this `header("Location: " . $redirect_url);`. You need to **return** that url to javascript and then redirect the user (NOT from php).

Comment: D'oh!!  Thank you so much.  Sometimes you just stare at a problem so long, all you see are characters mocking you.  I changed the last line to print "<script language=\"Javascript\">window.location='" . $redirect_url . "';</script>"; and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @machineaddict if you place that as the answer then I will mark it solved for you. :)

Comment: Don't worry mate. It's fine like this. The help is what matters.