# Difficulty in integrating PayPal in my project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I was following this tutorial for integrating PayPal-node-SDK in my project for Pay with PayPal option. 
http://devblog.paypal.com/building-a-web-app-with-node-js-the-paypal-sdk-part-3/

I'm getting following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=someToken. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Can anyone please help me out to resolve this issue? I'm using MEAN stack for my project.

Thanks

Edit: Updated Code for creating the paypal payment.

```
paypal.payment.create(payment, function (error, payment) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    if(payment.payer.payment_method === 'paypal') {
      //req.session.paymentId = payment.id;
      var redirectUrl;
      for(var i=0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
        var link = payment.links[i];
        if (link.method === 'REDIRECT') {
          redirectUrl = link.href;
          console.log(redirectUrl);
        }
      }
      res.redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS issue. You won't be able to query `sandbox.paypal.com` from a `localhost` domain using JavaScript (from within your browser). You either have to handle the requests through a backend, or you'll have to investigate how to get PayPal to allow your domain to be set as a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on their server (possibly registering a domain with them when you get an API key).

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about possible solutions? Right now, I'm sending the request from backend only. How can a register a domain with them, I already have an api key.? I want to do testing on my localhost. is there any way by which I can accomplish this?

Comment: See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994026/paypal-returning-access-control-allow-origin-error). Sounds like you're trying to do a GET request, when you should be redirecting the user instead.

Comment: I have updated my code. I'm using res.redirect() which doesn't seems to be working. PLease correct me if I'm doing any silly mistakes. I'm a bit new to JS.

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I'm new to node.js, I found this topic through the angular stream. But that should be working. Maybe there is another issue with your code. How exactly is your front and back-end interacting in this case?